# Routing a cgroup to a different table and back to the main table

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, cgroup

I want to have the following setup. There are two interfaces: `wlan0` and `wg0`. `wlan0` is the default, `wg0` is a wireguard interface, configured *manually*.

By default traffic goes to `wlan0`. But if a process is put inside a cgroup, say `wgcgrp` (classid is 1), traffic must go over the `wg0`.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. What I attempted is this. I will be very verbose, because I am very frustrated.

## [Wireguard Setup]

This is fairly simple, first `ip l a wg0 name wg0 type wireguard`. Then, I have a w.conf file, which contains data fed to `wg setconf wg0`. It sets private key, public key, allowed IPs (0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0) and the endpoint. *Nothing* more. Then I also set the IP address of the wg0 interface, which I know beforehand: `ip ad a $ip dev wg0; ip -6 ad a $ip6 dev wg0`. Now I add the route: `ip l s wg0 up; ip r a default dev wg0 t wg`

## [Firewall]

So far as I understand I must make the cgroup traffic to somehow reach the `wg` routing table. I know how to do this. I must mark the cgroup traffic inside a chain of the type `route` and then masquerade it. Here are the rules.

```
table inet t {
    chain post {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept
        meta cgroup 1 counter meta mark set meta cgroup
    }
    
    chain masq {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept
        meta cgroup 1 oifname "wg0" counter masquerade
    }
}
```

There are *no more* rules in my firewall.

## [Routes setup]

Marked traffic must get in the `wg` table, so I run `ip ru a fwmark 1 lookup wg`

## [Result]

`cgexec -g net_cls:wg ping 8.8.8.8`
and I get nothing. Why??? I do not even know how to start debugging. This should be simple, yet I am not even near.

Comment: What do you mean by "get nothing", the ping timed out? What distro+fw? iptables has a `--cgroup` parameter for rules, like `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x1 -j MARK --set-mark 1`, then forward to route table with `ip rule add fwmark 1 table wg`. Compare to the steps here: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~emeitner/bypassing-a-vpn-using-cgroups.html ? If you don't get something here, I'd recommend asking over on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Packets are sent to `wg0`, but never come back. Debian 12, nftables. As for bypassing VPN guide, I had the exact same setup and point is it WORKS. I expected the reverse to work as well, but I am out of luck. I really can not understand why. Maybe I will cross post on stackexchange a bit later.

Comment: Well, I have just tried to do the exact same thing, but instead of wireguard openvpn with --route-noexec flag and it just works. Really strange issues with this wireguard. Maybe it's time to learn tcpdump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears you need `ip r a "$endpoint_ip" dev wlan0 via "$wlan0_gateway" t wg` to make this setup work. It was very unexpected for me, because openVPN works without this additional route. Would be very thankful if anyone knows and explains why it is so. Maybe because openVPN is a userspace process, while wireguard runs in kernel and does routing differently?